# Webmatrix 3 hangs while querying cmsDocument table in SQL Server CE Database Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, webmatrix

Webmatrix is hanged while I query cmsDocument table in SQL CE database, I can query other tables but this gives me error, and it says that "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.". I also found out that cmsDocumentType table query is also a problem. How will I fix this?

And another issue is the content, document type and template I created previously are gone and just the old content is available. I renamed the main node in umbraco 6.16 site and added new nodes , saved and published. Now all new contents are lost.

I think these two issues are linked. I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that after there is any change in the content, the whole website should be refreshed in the WebMatrix. Otherwise, all the changes will be disappeared when the project is closed.